# Como recorro una lista con while y devuelvo item

Tags: java, poo

la consulta es la siguiente necesito hacer un metodo que me busque por ID los productos de una lista de productos. Como hago yo para recorrer dicha lista y que corte cuando encuentra el producto? Yo lo hice con un foreach, donde por cada producto de la lista guardaba el producto y comparaba el id de ese mismo con el id que me llegaba por parametro, pero claro, me dijeron que no puedo cortar ciclos foreach deben terminar el ciclo entero. Como hago esto pero con un while?

```
public Producto traerProdcuto(int idProducto) throws Exception{
    for(Producto p:gondola) {
        if(p.getIdProducto()==idProducto) {
            return p;
        }   
    }throw new NullPointerException("No se ha encontrado el producto");

}
```

Lo que intente fue esto luego fue esto:

```
public Producto traerProducto(int idProducto)throws Exception {
        boolean found = false;
        int vueltas  = 0;
        
        while(found==false) {
            Producto p = gondola.get(vueltas);
            if(p.getIdProducto() ==idProducto) {
                found =true;
                return p;
            }
            vueltas++;
            
        }
        
        throw new Exception("El producto con la id: "+idProducto+", no se ha encontrado");
    }
```

El problema que tengo es que sigo interrumpiendo un ciclo sin respetar la condicion, y si no hay ningun producto con ese ID sigue iterando luego de terminada la lista y tira una excepcion

Comment: Cuál lista de productos? Cuál foreach? Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Soy ignorante en [tag:Java]. Pero, no creo que pueda existir un lenguaje en el que los ciclos de control no puedan ser interrumpidos **y alguien lo use**. Con seguridad debe existir en java una instrucción como **break;** o similar para salirse de un bucle. Y, si no la hay, todavía puedes **modificar el contador de iteraciones y hacerlo igual al límite**

Comment: A tu pregunta le falta: el código que tienes ahora mismo, los datos que estás intentando usar, la salida esperada, lo que intentaste para resolver lo que te piden. Por favor, usa el enlace 'editar' que está justo debajo, edítala y añade todo esto para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Ahi agregue lo que yo estoy haciendo pero me dijeron que es una mala practica por eso no se como resolverlo de otra manera. Gracias por los consejos!

Comment: no se quien te dijo que es una mala practica.. tal vez deberias preguntarle a esa persona porque es una mala practica y como resolverlo... si encontraste el item, sali con un break y listo...

Comment: Lo que si veo horrible, es tirar una excepcion porque no se encontro. Las excepciones son caras para el programa.. porque simplemente no devolves null si no se encuentra? de esa forma, hasta el codigo es mas simple...

Comment: Mi profesor nos dijo que es mala practica usar un for y no dejar que termine su ciclo si uno le puso un determinado recorrido al for dejarlo que termine porque si uno tiene que debuguear cuando ves un for das por hecho que termina cuando dice la condicion y si el for tiene breaks se pueden escapar detalles y errores.

Comment: bueno eso es cuestionable... da para discutir... si tenes que recorrer mil elementos y lo encontaste en la segunda vuelta, vale la pena dar 998 vueltas mas?

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, por eso. Pero todas las soluciones que encuentro yo es cortando los bucles jajaja asi que no se

Comment: Primer profesor que veo que le gusta siempre caer en el peor escenario de complejidad de tiempo jejeje desde por acá en la industria, puedo decir que los estándares de codificación, aunque siguen buenas prácticas conocidas, terminan siendo cosa casi que de cada equipo / proyecto / empresa. Sabio es entonces preguntar y llegar a acuerdos (como en cualquier trabajo) sobre cuáles son los estándares comunes, por qué y ofrecer el punto de vista propio.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estas haciendo deberia funcionar correctamente.
Es una cuestion de estilo de programacion ya que ambos daran el mismo resultado.

La forma de hacerlo sin cortar la ejecucion del resto de la funcion es aplicando instruccion break en el for;
La instruccion return es final y prevendra que otras lineas despues de tu for incluidas en el metodo traerProducto se ejecuten, pero no quiere decir que este mal.

Por ejemplo, si el objectivo de la funcion traerProducto es encontrar el producto que estas buscando, no veo razon para crear variables y asignarles valores para retornarlos "por fuera del loop"

Ejemplo:

```
public Producto traerProdcuto(int idProducto) throws Exception {
    Producto productoEncontrado;
    for(Producto p:gondola) {
        if(p.getIdProducto()==idProducto) {
            productoEncontrado = p;
            break;
        }   
    }

    if (!productoEncontrado) {
       throw new NullPointerException("No se ha encontrado el producto");
    }
 
    return productoEncontrado;
}
```

En una instruccion while el "break" o instruccion de corte es evaluada por cada iteracion

```
public Producto traerProducto(int idProducto) throws Exception {
    int vueltas  = 0;
    Producto productoEncontrado;

    // Deberias agregar una segunda instruccion de corte en el caso en el que el producto no exista    
    //por ejemplo !productoEncontrado && vueltas >= totalProductos) 
    while(!productoEncontrado) {
        Producto p = gondola.get(vueltas);
        if(p.getIdProducto() ==idProducto) {
            found =true;
            productoEncontrado = p;
        }
        vueltas++;
    }

    return productoEncontrado;
}
```

Como podras ver el codigo de arriba deberia tener exactamente el mismo resultado, y pero los cambios aplicados son redundantes...
Como dato adicional, nunca quieres iterar en vano

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que tu profesor requiere que el return este fuera del while, de tal manera que la condición del while interrumpa la iteración, de tal manera que el returnes lo ultimo que se ejecutara, es cuestión de estilo, pero al final seguir las buenas practicas es lo importante, recomiendo revisar los libros de Cleancode y cleancoder

Comment: Esto no va como respuesta sino como comentario.